# What is the preferred web mapping solution for 'big data' (millions of vector records)?

Tags: web-apps, maps, gis, mapping

Looking for opinions and information related to online mapping solutions. I have dozens of vector-based datasets (containing 1000's of records; think 'big data') that need to be incorporated into an online web application, with search/geocoding functionality.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Open source? If not, what is your budget? Searching would be based on text associated with each vector I guess? About "geocoding": please give an example of what action your user would do that would trigger it, and what result would be shown to them. Thanks!

Comment: 1000s of records is hardly considered big data in the gis world